# Inversing integers and printing it in console

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array of integers, which have to be converted into its inverses, so that, my program reads a series of integers from a user, fills an array with it, and then print it's inverses in a writeline. I had an idea to put inversed integers into double array, but still I don't know how to inverse (so that it looks like that - 1/N) it.
Finally, inversed integers should be printed in WriteLines.

Comment: What do you want printed, eg for 2?  `0.5` or `1/2`.

Comment: If you want it to look like "1/N", print "1/N". Don't calculate anything. Just print it that way.

Comment: I want it printed 0.5

Comment: Be sure to cast it to a `double` (EDIT: or treat it as such, say by using `1.0 / N`) before the `1/N` expression to avoid integer truncation which would likely turn most of your numbers into `0`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `double inverse = 1.0 / number`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this should work:

```
int arrayOfIntegers[] = <Your Array of Integers>;
foreach (input in arrayOfIntegers){
   Console.WriteLine(1.0 / (double)in);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.Length(); i++)
{
     Console.WriteLine("1 / " + numbers[i].ToString());
}
```

or the `foreach` version:

```
foreach(int i in numbers)
{
     Console.WriteLine("1 / " + i.ToString());
}
```

or to get cute:

```
foreach(int i in numbers)
{
     Console.WriteLine("1 / {0} = {1}", i, 1.0 / i);
}
```

Comment: Hah, I like it. Smells like BS, but I like it. (would also look weird for negative values with the negative sign in the denominator) EDIT: Also, Artur specified that he wanted decimal values not fractions (e.g., 0.5 not 1/2)

Answer (score 0):

Of course this is a very basic exercise, I would like to introduce `LINQ` to you:

```
var output = yourArray.Select(x=> {
                     float f = 1f/x;
                     Console.Write(((decimal)f) + "  ");
                     return f;
                  }).ToArray();
//This way you can still store the array while print all the inversed elements
```

Comment: Why `x == 0 ? float.NegativeInfinity : 1f/x`? You could just `1f/x`, and ok 0 would come out as PositiveInfinity but you're not using that result anyway so..

Comment: @harold Thanks, I thought it will throw exception.

Comment: I advise against side-effects in queries when there are good alternatives like foreach.